# SSIS - ETL - Execution performance issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis, execution

We have a Production SSIS solution that we use as an ETL process. It's been in Production for over a year and has been running fine. However, literally overnight, the performance dropped like a stone. The volume of data moved and processed by the ETL isn't significantly different.

The ETL process is a pretty simple series of individual packages that are executed in parallel. It doesn't do anything particularly complex.

Nothing was deployed to the server and no configuration changes were made between the last 'good' run and the first 'bad' run, but suddenly it took three times as long as usual.

I've had a dig through the logs and I think I can see what is happening, but I don't know why. I've queried the **catalog.event_messages** view for one of the SSIS packages and found enormous delays between the different tasks within the package. I've had a look at a number of other packages and the same pattern is repeated - it looks like it's affecting all of them.

When I compare these to the entries from the day before (the last 'good' run) there are no delays. The packages just zip through from start to finish.

So it looks like the problem is with the sudden introduction of these delays between tasks within the various packages.

Here's an example. On the final 'good' run this package took < 1 sec to execute from start to finish, but the next night it took around 2 minutes to move the same volume of data.

```
2018-01-14 22:23:33.9631482 +00:00  EXTRACT_XXXXXXXXXX:Information: The package is attempting to configure from the parent variable "ProcessLogID".
2018-01-14 22:23:33.9631482 +00:00  EXTRACT_XXXXXXXXXX:Information: The package is attempting to configure from the parent variable "LoadID".
2018-01-14 22:24:02.7208761 +00:00  EXTRACT_XXXXXXXXXX:Validation has started.
2018-01-14 22:24:02.7208761 +00:00  EXTRACT_XXXXXXXXXX:Validation is complete.
...
...
```

So there's a 29 second gap between the second and third lines

A little further down for the same package we have :

```
...
2018-01-14 22:24:02.8146315 +00:00  Truncate existing data:Start, 22:24:02.
2018-01-14 22:24:30.9061374 +00:00  Truncate existing data:Validation has started.
2018-01-14 22:24:30.9061374 +00:00  Truncate existing data:Validation is complete.
2018-01-14 22:24:46.6667393 +00:00  Truncate existing data:Finished, 22:24:46, Elapsed time: 00:00:43.844.
...
...
```

So there's a 28 second gap between starting this task and the validation.

Later on we also have :

```
...
2018-01-14 22:24:57.9902520 +00:00  Data Flow Task:Information: The final commit for the data insertion in "OLE DB Destination" has started.
2018-01-14 22:25:11.9929728 +00:00  Data Flow Task:Information: The final commit for the data insertion  in "OLE DB Destination" has ended.
...
```

So there's another large gap there.

The previous night's entries for this package don't have any delays (the whole thing took < 1 sec).

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this?

There were no new deployments / configuration changes between the last 'good' and the first 'bad' run so nothing (or at least nothing obvious!) has changed.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: is there a chance that an external application is accessing either the source/target database during the package execution? can you run the package and recreate the issue and look for any locks/waits?

Comment: Thanks. I've been told that there shouldn't be anything else running on either the source or target DBs at the time.

Comment: has the server configuration changed at all: RAM / CPU settings? how much of the available memory are you allowing SQL Server to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update statistis of the database using this command :

```
EXEC sp_updatestats;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Your package is taking time in validation phase. Please test your package with "`Delay Validation=True`" for the tasks and see the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The packages already have the 'DelayValidation' set to true. The change in behaviour was literally overnight with no code deployment / config changes, so these setting would be the same for the 'good' and 'bad' runs.